# What's the best option for responsive drupal theme using sass, Zen sub-theme or twitter Bootstrap

Tags: theming

I am going to start a new project using sass but not sure whether I should use twitter bootstrap and start fro scratch or use [Zen](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen). Any suggestion on which one to use and why?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) The rules are the same here as on Stack Overflow (where I notice you have some experience) - asking for people's opinion's on the best theme to use, or even a particular theme to use for a particular situation, is off-topic here as there isn't an objective answer available. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more info on what to ask here

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion bootstrap, with bower you can download [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) in your theme folder really handy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with [Zen](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen) and create your own sub-theme from it. Because it is a powerful, yet simple, HTML5 [Starter Theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/323993) with a responsive, mobile-first grid design.

If you are building your own standards-compliant theme, you will find it much easier to start with Zen than to start with Garland or Stark. This theme has [fantastic online documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme/zen) and tons of helpful code comments in its PHP, HTML, CSS and Sass.

Comment: I would tend to agree with Zen being a good choice. However, unlike a theme like Omega, it is NOT well documented. The documentation seems to be hinged on a video apparently shot from the audience at a user conference in 2012. Both the audio and video SUCK!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tosJch150hA